# how to make a loop for opening different files with a non constant name

Tags: python

I am trying to analyze the data of several files with python and make an statistics, but the name of the files is not constant... I was reading some forums and I thought this could be a good solution, but is giving me errors for the % operand, and I think I might have wrote
something wrong... sorry but I am not good at programming

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import numpy as np
import os, os.path
import fileinput
from glob import glob

val = 0
seq = 0


out = open('../stats.txt', 'w')
while out:

    fnames = glob('../cmsearch_all/RF(%d)_*.txt') % val #here val vhanges from 00003 to infinite without being consecutive numbers, and the * was denoting to ignore tha prt because is not constant not even on numer of characters

    for line in fileinput.input(fnames):
        w = count (line,"!Myodav*") 
        wa = count (line,"!Myotri*")
        wb = count (line,"!Tricot*") #here I was hoping to be counting the number of times !Tricot appears, but the line in the file actually looks like !Tricot_123_fromdatabase812hg243538dth but I care just when this !Tricot appears 

    fnames = glob('../cmsearch_all/RF(%d)_*.final.txt') % val

    for line in fileinput.input(fnames):
        x = count (line,">Myodav*") 
        xa = count (line,">Myotri*")
        xb = count (line,">Tricot*")        



        out.write(val + "\t" + w + "\t" + x + "\t" + wa + "\t" + xa + "\n") #here I think I will have to specified everything individually as a string... 
        print val + "\t" + w + "\t" + x + "\t" + wa + "\t" + xa + "\n"
        val += 1
```

sorry if what I wrote is too weird, and if you know where could I read about this would be nice to know, thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What errors do you get?

Maybe you should replace

```
fnames = glob('../cmsearch_all/RF(%d)_*.final.txt') % val
```

with

```
fnames = glob('../cmsearch_all/RF(%d)_*.final.txt' % val)
```

because `glob()` does not return a string.

Comment: yo@:~/Desktop/scripts$ python stats.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stats.py", line 17, in <module>
    fnames = glob('../cmsearch_all/RF(%d)_*.txt') % val
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'

Comment: yo@:~/Desktop/scripts$ python stats.py
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "stats.py", line 19, in <module>
    for line in fileinput.input(fnames):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/fileinput.py", line 253, in next
    line = self.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/fileinput.py", line 346, in readline
    self._buffer = self._file.readlines(self._bufsize)
KeyboardInterrupt ... the second error was after moving the brackets, because it was not printing anything at the end of the loop

Comment: after fnames I am trying to print fnames and the output is : [] and then nothing else

Comment: Can you give an example filename, that should match `RF(%d)_*.final.txt`?

Comment: RF00015_Camion.final.txt, RF00120_Tortuga.final.txt, RF00002_Dlor.final.txt

Comment: `glob` searches for files looking like `RF(1)_*.txt` for `val=1`. It should look like `RF%5d_*.txt`.

Comment: fnames = glob('../cmsearch_all/RF%5d_*.fa' % val), continues printing [] when I ask to print fnames